# Possible placeholders in sources.list

Tags: software-sources

Official man `sources.list(5)` mentions only `$(ARCH)` placeholder.

I wonder if there are any other placeholders are available, like `$(CODENAME)`.

Comment: A brief scan of the apt source code. specifically in `apt-pkg/sourcelist.cc` suggests not, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only ARCH and VERSION are available (as explained in the man page). VERSION needs to bet set up to work.

Any other alteration is generally done by using `sed` and appending or replacing a value.

> The following variable substitutions are done on sources.list entries:
>
> - $(ARCH) is substituted with the base architecture of the system.
> - $(VERSION) is substituted with the distribution version if configured automatically via Apt::DistroVerPkg or manually via the
>   Apt::DistroVersion configuration option.

Comment: Confirming: I saw many projects embed code name via `sed`/`bash` or other template solutions.